# Concat () function or alternative solution in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a character before/after value in mysql query. but I can't make it work. 
This is the part that doesn't work in my case:

```
$query = "select CONCAT ('.', DuRpt) as DuRpt, DaRpt from DDtb order by DATE DESC";
```

You can see the full code below. Any ideas why it doesn't work or can I get an alternative solution, please. thanks.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<?php

include ("etc/config.php");

$query = "select concat ('.', DuRpt) as DuRpt, DaRpt from DDtb order by DATE DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $message = 'ERROR:' . mysqli_error($link); 
    return $message; 
} else { 
    $i = 0; 
    echo '<form name="select" action="" method="GET">';
    echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"  size="44" onchange="this.form.submit()">'; 
    while ($i < mysqli_field_count($link)) { 
        $meta =  
            mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
        echo '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>'; 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    } 
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';
}

    ?>

   </div>
  <div>

  <?php

if(isset($_GET['mySelect'])) {
    $myselect = $_GET['mySelect']; 
    $sql = "SELECT `$myselect` as mySelect from DDtb order by DATE DESC";   
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);   

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        $table_row_counter = 3;
        echo '<table>';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $table_row_counter++;
            if ($table_row_counter % 30 == 1) {
                echo '</table>';
                echo '<table>';
            }

            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["mySelect"] . "</td></tr>";

        }
    }
} 

echo '</table>';
mysqli_close($link);
?> 

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What does the format of your DDtb look like?

Comment: I don't get any error. and the strange thing is the results are output without the character (.), I only get the plain results.

Comment: Where would you expect the result to be output? I don't see DuRpt anywhere besides your query...

Comment: DuRpt is displayed in selectbox, and when clicked the results are displayed. DuRpt becomes myselect in this case.

Comment: ah, I see, so $myselect gets the value of 'DuRpt', and your 2nd query just ends up being "SELECT `DuRpt` as mySelect from DDtb order by DATE DESC"

Comment: I should also mention the way you have it is open to sql injection. Someone could provide a nasty value for $_GET['mySelect'] and run any query, including deleting all your data

Comment: Do you only want to add the . character for DuRpt ? what about doing it in php instead?

Comment: thanks. but I still couldn't find a solution, and don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I am open for a php solution too. but i may have several fields like this. and not sure how in this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176915/discussion-between-khartnett-and-max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2nd half of your code, you can do this:
note you won't need to concat anything in your initial query

```
if(isset($_GET['mySelect'])) {
    // configure every option here, if there's not pre/postfix, use a blank string
    $prepostfixes = [
        'DuRpt' => ['.', '.'],
        'DaRpt' => ['', ''],
    ];
    $myselect = $_GET['mySelect'];
    if (!isset($prepostfixes[$myselect])) {
        die ('Unknown Select'); // this will prevent sql injection
    }
    $sql = "SELECT `$myselect` as mySelect from DDtb order by DATE DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        $table_row_counter = 3;
        echo '<table>';
        $prefix = $prepostfixes[$myselect][0];
        $postfix = $prepostfixes[$myselect][1];

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $table_row_counter++;
            if ($table_row_counter % 30 == 1) {
                echo '</table>';
                echo '<table>';
            }

            echo "<tr><td>" . $prefix . $row["mySelect"] . $postfix . "</td></tr>";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code and remove the duplicate of `DuRpt` from it.

```
$query = "select concat ('.', DuRpt) as DuRpt from DDtb order by DATE DESC";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean with the duplicate of DuRpt. I tried your suggestion in the code, it didn't work.

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: phpmyadmin -> your database, click on SQL (beside the Structure) and execute `select concat ('.', DuRpt) as DuRpt from DDtb order by DATE DESC` and let me know the result.

Comment: in phpmyadmin, it works. I mean the character (.) is added to the field value. but it's not working in the code.

Comment: if it works from phpmyadmin, then it should work within your code and give you the same result.

Comment: `
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 2
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1134
    [type] => 0
)
this is the result.

Comment: why `DuRpt` not there?

Comment: I don't know. This is the output of the code you wanted me to try.

Comment: thanks. I got a solution now. Apparently the two sql queries don't match each other. so we went through a php solution.

Comment: that's ok, have a nice day.